# Is there an x86 opcode for moving an immediate byte to a direct memory location (without using registers)?

Tags: assembly, x86, opcode, instruction-encoding

Is there a way to 'mov'e a specific immediate byte-size number into a direct memory location? I.e.

```
MOV 10h,ffffh
```

to write the value `16` into the memory address `65535`? If so, which opcode is that, orwould I have to store a memory address into a register first?

Comment: In Intel syntax, `mov byte ptr [0ffffh], 10h`. In AT&T syntax,`movb $0x10, 0xffff`. Consult your assembler documentation for more details.

Answer (score 15):

Yes.  The opcode is `C6`.  You should download a copy of the Intel ISA documents, which are [freely available](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html).

To your follow-up question: the full encoding of your example is:

```
  c6      04      25   ff ff 00 00   10
opcode  modr/m   sib     address     immediate
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen, however doesn't instruction C6 require a r/m byte? If that is the case, then the resulting instruction is only four bytes long, surely not enough to hold a complete memory address?

Comment: @Nicholas Hill: the resulting instruction is *not* only 4 bytes long.

Answer (score 10):

**[Intel Manual Volume 2 Instruction Set Reference - 325383-056US September 2015](https://web.archive.org/web/20151025081307/http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf)** Section 3.2 "MOV—Move
" has a table which contains:

```
Opcode            Instruction
----------------  ----------------
C6 /0 ib          MOV r/m8, imm8
C7 /0 iw          MOV r/m16, imm16
C7 /0 id          MOV r/m32, imm32
REX.W + C7 /0 io  MOV r/m64, imm32
```

Then you must know that:

- `r/m` means register or memory location
- `imm` means immediate

So those are the encodings you are looking for.

More empirically you could also have just tried it out and decompiled:

```
mov byte [0x1234678], 0x9A
```

Then:

```
as --32 -o a.o a.S
nasm -felf32 -o a.o a.asm
```

Gives:

```
00000000 <.text>:
   0:    c6 05 78 56 34 12 9a    movb    $0x9a,0x12345678
```

So we conclude that `c6` is the opcode, with ModR/M `05`, and immediates following.

Comment: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov has the manual entry you're quoting.  [How to read the Intel Opcode notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53976236) details how to read the `/0` part (and the other answer there has info on reading the rest of the entry).